# @timestamp field not identified in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, date-formatting

I am pushing some old logs to elasticsearch via rsyslog.

Here is one of the log entries,

```
[START] --- [xx.xx.xx.xx] --- [25/Jun/2017:06:39:54 +0530] --- "Headers: [-, -, -, -, -, -]" --- "POST /infotrack HTTP/1.1" --- 200 --- 0.310 --- "-" --- "Java/1.8.0_121" --- "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" --- "-" --- [END]
```

The logs are successfully inside the elasticsearch and visible in kibana.

But the @timestamp is not identified. During adding index in kibana, the time field does not shows up.

What is the problem here ?

[image]

I have used the same format timestamp in other indices and it did not create any problem there.

Answer (score 0):

Are you indexing those Nginx logs via Logstash?
Please show us the Logstash filter configuration or the mapping you specified for the elasticsearch @timestamp field.

Most likely you defined a wrong date format in the Logstash conf or in the Elasticsearch mapping, provided example `25/Jun/2017:06:39:54 +0530` doesn't seem to fit any [built in format](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-date-format.html#built-in-date-formats) so you may have to define a [custom one](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-date-format.html#custom-date-formats).

Comment: I see the dateformat is wrong. I am not using logstash. I think I have to define a custom dateformat